# How to write for loop to perform jar task multiple times with different parameters?

Tags: groovy, build.gradle

I have multiple clones defined in gradle.properties as `cloneId = clone1,clone2`. I need to run the jar task in build gradle for each of this clone. I guess I can use for loop but I don't know how to use it as I am new to groovy and gradle. It works fine for a single clone if its `cloneId= clone1`. But I want it for multiple clones.

build.gradle file

```
jar {



    def jarTargetDir = file("lib")

       archiveBaseName = cloneId


       destinationDir = file("$rootDir/"+cloneId+"War/lib")


}
```

gradle.properties

```
cloneId=clone1,clone2
```

Comment: All your clones are the same contents, just a different name?

Comment: Yes thats right tim_yates